# How to disable screen lock in Ubuntu 14.04 / Unity?

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen

I disabled the lock in the "Brightness & Lock" but I still get the lock screen when is resumes/wake from suspend. Although the option "Require my password when waking from suspend" is unchecked

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is two steps involved into completely disabling the lock screen in Unity.

1. Go to `Brightness & Lock` panel from the Unity Launcher. And set `Turn screen off when inactive:` to `Never`
2. Install "Unity Tweak Tool" with `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`. Run it from the Launcher and select `System > Security > Enhance system security by disabling Desktop lock`

Answer (score 0):

go to search , type Unity, in the options displayed find and double click on option "Unity Tweak Tool", a windows opens inside that you will find main options like

Unity

Windows Manager

Appearance

System

under "system" there are 3 sub option "Desktop" , "Security", "Scrolling"

- click on security, under security tab do a check on option "Desktop Lock"

I am adding this solution just in case if unable to find the option.

Thanks for the all previous post's. very helpful and informative.

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me, but I found some info in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-locker/+bug/1287255).

As a result of what I read in the bug I ended up doing this:

```
sudo mv /etc/xdg/autostart/light-locker.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/light-locker.desktop.bak
```

That seemed to do the trick.